# `no ip bootp server` appear in `sh run`

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst

My understanding on Cisco devices is if we put `no` command in the `config mode`, that particular line will be gone from `sh run`.

But I notice there is specific line in `sh run` with `no ip bootp server` inside one of the `Cisco Catalyst 9300 Series Switches`.

Shouldn't this be gone when we put `no` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding on Cisco devices is if we put `no` command in the `config mode`, that particular line will be gone from `sh run`.

Your understanding is flawed. While this is commonly the case, in this particular case it is not so.

Unfortunately, Cisco is not fully consistent in how they display configurations, although there are a few general rules of thumb. Most default configuration statements are not shown unless you do a `show running-config all` while changes to the default configuration are shown.

> Shouldn't this be gone when we put `no` command?

In the particular version of software you are running, the `ip bootp server` statement is the default configuration. It was likely not shown in a `show running-config` initially, but would show up in the `show running-config all`.

When you change the default to `no ip bootp server` you have now changed it from the default and the configuration will be show. If you were to enter `ip bootp server` in config mode, it will likely disappear again from a `show running-config`.